# how to fire button click event from page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have 2 textbox control that are prepopulated with some default dates using j-query when the page loads.  So when the page loads, my GridView is supposed to load with some data based on the Dates that are in those 2 textbox controls.  But the problem is that the GridView is not loaded with any data on the page load,  BUT the gridview is loaded only after I click the Generate Report button which populates the gridview.   I have tried to call the function that populates the gridview  from the Page Load but it did not help.  So I found this code that fires the button click event and it seems it is working but the problem is that it is keep looping and looping… please help I am open to any suggestion. Thanks
Here is the j-query that fires the btnClick Event but it is keep looping..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   //this calls the btnClick event but it is looping..
   $("[id*='btnClick']").click();
});
</script>
```

and here is my other codes on the page

```
<%@ Page Title="My Metrics" ClientIDMode="Static" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Summary.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//here is the jquery that populates my textbox controls

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#txtStartClosingDate").datepicker();
               $("#txtEndClosingDate").datepicker();
               var startdate = new Date();
               startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
               $("#txtStartClosingDate").datepicker("setDate", startdate);
               var endDate = new Date(); // current date
               endDate.setDate(1); // going to 1st of the month
               endDate.setHours(-1);
               $("#txtEndClosingDate").datepicker("setDate", endDate);
           });
    </script>
```

Comment: Does your button fire a postback? If so, your code would execute endlessly: Invoke click, postback, load page, invoke click, postback, load page, etc...

Comment: why not move the logic for your button click into the page load or call it on page load as well as button click so that you don't have to physically click the button the first time

Comment: i moved the button click logic into my page load but still it did not help.  I think my page is loading faster before it even populated the 2 textbox controls.

Comment: ah right so you're populating your datepickers with jquery too - why not move this into the code behind as well then you can set them and then show the results on page load, wrap that in a not page.ispostback and it won't interfere with your button click

Comment: i only know how to do that using the jquery..

Comment: have added a jquery workaround

Answer (score 0):

The click handler that you are trying to trigger is most likely also attached via $(document).ready(). What is probably happening is that you are triggering the event before the handler is attached. The solution is to use setTimeout:
Use this instead.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("[id*='btnClick']").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

Comment: i did this but still it is looping.  i am suspecting the page load even t is firing faster than before the 2 textbox controls is populated.  the gridview is populated based on the date range that is specified in those controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think your button is firing a postback and that is what is causing the loop.

To fix it, you could put the controls that need updating inside an ajax panel

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the different events the loading-process offers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

For example use Page - LoadComplete = Raised at the end of the event-handling stage. Use this event for tasks that require that all other controls on the page be loaded.